# How to set up partial table replication?

Tags: database-replication, data-synchronization

There exist replication mechanisms for master-master and master-slave. What I'm looking for is something like master-master, but with a serious twist. I have no idea if something like this exists or in what direction to start looking for it - any pointers, even if they're not definitive answers, would be appreciated.

Assume:

- I have databases in 3 data centers, geographically distant (ping > 40ms).
- The databases have a shared data model, ie table A in database 1 will have the same fields as table A in database 2 and table A in database 3.
- Each database, 1, 2 and 3, are being filled with data from local systems, but all according to the shared data model.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- I want to replicate all data from table A in database 2 to table A in database 1 (master-master).
- I want to replicate all data from table A in database 3 to the same table A in database 1 (master-master), but without replicating the data from database 2 to database 3.

So I want to replicate data from two databases in a single table in database 1. Or find a way to set it up in such a way that data seems to be (transparently) available from table A for connecting users / applications.

If feasible, the replication should work over different technologies (eg assuming database 1 is Oracle, database 2 is Teradata, database 3 is MSSQL).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to set up master-master replication for the tables (using A', A'' on database 1) and creating a view (A) on database 1 which unions tables A' and A''.

I do have concerns about performance though, and do not consider this an ideal solution.